# What exceptions can occur when saving an XDocument?

Tags: c#, exception, linq-to-xml

In my C# application I'm using the following statement:

```
public void Write(XDocument outputXml, string outputFilename) {
  outputXml.Save(outputFilename);
}
```

How can I find out which exceptions the `Save` method might throw? Preferably right in Visual Studio 2012 or alternatively in the MSDN documentation.

[XDocument.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) does not give any references. It does for other methods, e.g. `File.IO.Open`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately MSDN do not have any information about exceptions thrown by `XDocument` and many other types from *System.Xml.Linq* namespace.

But here is how saving implemented:

```
public void Save(string fileName, SaveOptions options)
{
    XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = XNode.GetXmlWriterSettings(options);
    if ((declaration != null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(declaration.Encoding))
    {
        try
        {
            xmlWriterSettings.Encoding = 
               Encoding.GetEncoding(declaration.Encoding);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
        }
    }

    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileName, xmlWriterSettings))    
        Save(writer);        
}
```

If you will dig deeper, you'll see that there is large number of possible exceptions. E.g. `XmlWriter.Create` method can throw `ArgumentNullException`. Then it creates `XmlWriter` which involves `FileStream` creation. And here you can catch `ArgumentException`, `NotSupportedException`, `DirectoryNotFoundException`, `SecurityException`, `PathTooLongException` etc.

So, I think you should not try to catch all this stuff. Consider to wrap any exception in application specific exception, and throw it to higher levels of your application:

```
public void Write(XDocument outputXml, string outputFilename) 
{
   try
   {
       outputXml.Save(outputFilename);
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       throw new ReportCreationException(e); // your exception type here
   } 
}
```

Calling code can catch only `ReportCreationException` and log it, notify user, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the MSDN doesn't state any I guess that Class won't throw any exception. Although, I don't think that this object will be responsible for writing the actual file to disk. So you might receive exceptions from other classes used by `XDocument.Save();`

To be on the safe side, I would trap all exceptions and try out some obvious erratic instructions, see below.

```
try
{
  outputXml.Save("Z:\\path_that_dont_exist\\filename");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Here, catching Exception will catch any types of exceptions.